# My code for finding the last element in doubly linked list is throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am fairly new to programming and I am on my  way of learning C .I am trying to build a fully functional doubly linked list module but I am getting a segmentation fault while fetching the last element.

My function for the same

```
void get_last(struct Node *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        while (node->next)
        {
           node = node->next;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",node->prev->value);
}
```

Now every time I run it it throws an segmentation fault and I am not able to successfully debug it although I  find this conceptually correct as since node will eventually point to NULL when the loop ends and my code will print the value of the previous item .
Please correct me if I am wrong in my concept .
Thanks

edit : I have used `"%d"` in `printf()` as the values are integer values in my created linked list

edit 1:here is the code for creating linked list :

```
void create_list(struct Node *node)
{
    int i;

    first.next=NULL;
    first.prev=NULL;

    node=&first;

    for(i=1;i <=10;i++)
    {
        node->next=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->next->prev=node;
        node=node->next;

        node->value=rand()%20;
        node->next=NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough code to tell. How do we know `node->prev` is not null? Do some more debugging and find out exactly where the seg fault is coming from.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't use this syntax `printf("%d",node->prev->value);` it's not good to do that, `struct Node *previous = node->prev; if (previous) printf("%d\n", previous->value);` is better. And your last element is `node` because you are iterating until `node->next == NULL` which should happen at the last element, but your code cannot explain the behavior you describe, more is needed.

Comment: @iharob If `node` is `head` then `node->prev` will be `NULL`, so yes, this is exactly the problem.

Comment: @Austin I am posting as an answer

Comment: Only if he doesn't wrap the next and prev pointers. I usually have the `next` in the last entry point to `head` and `head`'s `prev` points to the last in the list.

Comment: this downvoting is demotivating ,how will a new person will learn if she or he  does not get her or his  doubts clarified by exp people .is this site meant to help only experienced programmers

Comment: That's a good question. It's for learning, but questions about implementing link lists almost always come from students working on homework, and SO is not for homework help. Teachers, fellow students, textbooks, and Wikipedia should suffice for that. Many SO users feel that it is morally wrong for them to assist with homework because you should be graded on your abilities alone. If you're working on your own and you encounter a problem that you can't find any other information about, that would warrant an SO question.

Comment: I am a social science student with no link to programming in my life,I am learning on my own and trying to build a module of fully operational doubly linked list .I have a specific error which I think wikipedia or books cant solve .Any way i will eventually figure it out

Comment: Your `create_list` does not initialize `node->prev`. You also lose your pointer to the first element in the list when you malloc the new node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the printf statement inside the `if (node)` block, otherwise you have a guaranteed segfault if called with a null pointer.

Next, presumably this is meant to print the value of the last entry in the list, not fetch the last entry.

From your code you have chosen to set `next` to `NULL` in the last entry (and presumably this means you set `prev` to `NULL` in the list head?). If so, you lose one of the main advantages of a doubly linked list over a singly linked one (not having to iterate through the list to find the last item.

If instead you had a fixed "head" node, and had your last item point to it in `next`, and the head's `prev` point to the last item, then you can fetch the last item with a single statement:

```
last = head.prev;
```

An iteration (for example a linear search) can terminate when `node->next == &head`.

However, your code as it stands will exit as follows

- If the list is empty (`node == NULL`) it will segfault on the `printf`
- If `node` is non-null, but `node->next == NULL` then presumably `node->prev == NULL` so it will segfault again.
- If there are some entries in the list, and the `while` terminates correctly, it would only segfault if `node->prev` is `NULL` (which suggests your error may also lie in the `add` method.

When implementing any datastructure, or any generic 'class' (even if it's in C), part of the definition of the **implementation** needs to be a set of invariants. These are things which your implementation guarantees to be true at all times.

In the case of a doubly linked list, these might be

- A node in the list consists of two pointers (`next` and `prev`) and a payload.
- Every list has a well-known node referred to as the `head`.
- The head node has no payload (associated value).
- For all nodes in the list, `(prev != NULL) && (next != NULL)`
- For any node `n`, `n->prev->next == n` and `n->next->prev == n`
- In an empty list, `(head->next == head->prev) && (head->next == head)`

Thus you can define a basic, generic, structure for the links in any list

```
// Forward declaration so the structure can point to itself
struct dll_links;

// The actual overhead of a DLL
typedef struct dll_links
{
    struct dll_links *next;
    struct dll_links *prev;
    struct dll_links *head;
} dll_links, dll_head;

// A simple macro to cast linkable datastructures as a set of links.
#define AS_LINKS(n) ((dll_links *) n)
```

and use it to define your own `Node` datastructure. Note that I include a reference to the list
head in evry node. This allows the implementation to detect attempts at violating the invariants (such as removing the `head` element).

```
typedef struct
{
    dll_links link;
    int value;
} Node;
```

Now, given a `Node *n`, you can access the links as `n->link.prev` and `n->link.next`.

So, given the above, a function to initialise a new list would be

```
void dll_init(dll_head *list)
{
    list->next = list.prev = list;
    list->head = list;
}
```

and would be used thus:

```
...
dll_head myList;
dll_init(&myList);
...
```

Note that this enforces all of the invariants.

The only other operations performed on a doubly linked list are insertion and removal

```
// Insert a new node in front of an existing one
void dll_insert(dll_links *newNode, dll_links *before)
{
    dll_links *orignalPrevious = before->prev;

    // First set up the links in the new node
    newNode->prev = originalPrevious;
    newNode->next = before;
    newNode->head = before->head;

    // Now link it in by adjusting the pointers of the surrounding nodes
    before->prev = newNode;
    originalPrevious->next = newNode;
}

// Remove a specified node from a list (and return it)
dll_links *dll_remove(dll_links *node)
{
    // Check the assertion that you can not remove the head element
    assert (node->head != node);

    dll_links *successor = node->next;
    dll_links *predecessor = node->prev;

    // Remove the element from the list
    predecessor->next = successor;
    successor->prev = predecessor;

    // Ensure no dangling pointers in the removed element
    node->next = node->prev = node->head = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

With these three functions, your `create_list` function looks like this:

```
void create_list(dll_head *list)
{
    int i;

    dll_init(list);

    for(i=1;i <=10;i++)
    {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->value=rand()%20;
        dll_insert(AS_LINKS(node), list); // Append the new node to the list
    }
}

...
{
    dll_head myList;
    create_list(&myList);
    ...
}
```

Iterating over the list, extracting the first or last entry, etc, is left as an exercise. But consider that
appending an entry is inserting *before* the head, inserting at the front is inserting before `head->next`,
the `head` element instantly knows which nodes are at the beginning and end of the list, and so on.

And the use of the `dll_links` approach means none of the operations need to know anything about the actual
node structures and payload. These functions can link *anything* (including heteregenous lists).

Comment: *otherwise you have a guaranteed segfault if called with a null pointer*, not really true.

Comment: When would `printf( "%d", ((struct Node *) NULL)->prev->value)` not generate a segfault (on a target machine which generates such traps)?

Comment: It causes undefined behavior, today someone had a `NULL` dereference that wasn't causing a segmentation fault [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28995317/1983495), you can see that in that case, the problem was discovered because of the excelenet [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) tool.

Comment: That would only be the case if the target machine's representation of a NULL pointer was 0x08 which is what Valgrind is saying was actually being dereferenced. It added the struct member's offset to 0 (the NULL representation in this case) and then dereferenced the result. That is not a dereference of a NULL pointer, but of an invalid one.

Comment: Hi I understand what you are trying to convey ,thanks for clearing my head,but not able to figure out how to put it in code .
shall I create a pointer to hold the last value while creating the list ,if so how do I initialize it  ?pardom my limited knowledge

Comment: Hopefully this helps you. It's just one implementation and may guide you in redesigning your own - which I recommend as an exercise in itself.

Comment: Thank you so much ,finally I made it without segmentation fault .Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this syntax `printf("%d",node->prev->value);` it's not good to do that

```
 struct Node *previous = node->prev;
 if (previous != NULL) 
     printf("%d\n", previous->value);
```

is better, since when `node` is the first node, `node->prev == NULL`, and there you will have problems.

Also your last element is `node` because you are iterating until `node->next == NULL` which should happen at the last element, but your code cannot explain the behavior you describe, more is needed

Comment: @chux that's what I initially had in my comment.